# Push commits to multiple remotes

Tags: git

I forked a repository and committed some files and created a pull request to origin repository.

Is it possible if I make other changes in files to push only to my local copy of the original repository? So the commits to not appear on the original repository.

I see that with `git push origin master` I see my commits in the original repository.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible if I make other changes in files to push only to my local copy of the original repository?

You should add multiple remotes if you don't have them yet.

#### How to add new remote?

```
git remote add <remote_name> url
```

Now you can push your branch to any remote

```
git push <remote_name> master
```

#### How to get the list of all remotes?

```
git remote --vv
```

If you want the push the same ranch to multiple remotes you can do this:

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin <url1>
git remote set-url --add --push origin <url2>
```

---

Your `.git/config` should look like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://original/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = git://original/repo.git
    pushurl = git://another/repo.git
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this after I used the new remote i deleted it. And now I keep getting the error .gitignore file permission denied and I can't do push. Do you know why ?